# MySQL Get all rows that appeared more than the average appearance

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of actors, where each actor appeared in different films, and I try to select only the actors that appeared more than the average appearance per actor.

Here is my try, but the result yields the same name with different values of appearances, hence I think I have a mistake

```
 SELECT 
   a.first_name AS fname, 
   a.last_name AS lname, 
   films_per_actor.num_films 
 FROM 
   actor as a, 
   (
     SELECT 
       AVG(num_films) AS avg_films_num 
     FROM 
       (
         SELECT 
           COUNT(film_id) AS num_films, 
           a.actor_id 
         FROM 
           film_actor as f_a, 
           actor as a 
         WHERE 
           f_a.actor_id = a.actor_id 
         GROUP BY 
           actor_id
       ) as films_per_actor1
   ) as avg_films, 
   (
     SELECT 
       COUNT(film_id) AS num_films, 
       a.actor_id 
     FROM 
       film_actor as f_a, 
       actor as a 
     WHERE 
       f_a.actor_id = a.actor_id 
     GROUP BY 
       actor_id
   ) as films_per_actor 
 WHERE 
   films_per_actor.num_films > avg_films.avg_films_num + 10 
 ORDER BY 
   fname, 
   lname
```

but the result is

```
"ADAM"  "GRANT" "40"
"ADAM"  "GRANT" "39"
"ADAM"  "GRANT" "42"
"ADAM"  "GRANT" "41"
"ADAM"  "HOPPER"    "40"
"ADAM"  "HOPPER"    "39"
"ADAM"  "HOPPER"    "42"
"ADAM"  "HOPPER"    "41"
"AL"    "GARLAND"   "40"
"AL"    "GARLAND"   "39"
"AL"    "GARLAND"   "41"
"AL"    "GARLAND"   "42"
"ALAN"  "DREYFUSS"  "39"
"ALAN"  "DREYFUSS"  "40"
"ALAN"  "DREYFUSS"  "42"
"ALAN"  "DREYFUSS"  "41"
```

Comment: Decoding your query without any data is a little too much to ask from us. Please share the sample input and expected output.

Comment: Mayank, Thanks a lot for the answer, An edited minimal question will be uploaded, thanks!
Strawberry, Sometimes, I just can't believe how much people here can be full of themselves just because it's virtual and everything can be said.
There are ways to say stuff.

Comment: @Strawberry I get your humor but I get flagged for leaving such comments. Be careful, my friend.

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 20 years.

Comment: Sample input???  How can we help when there's no data to test?

Comment: Please follow the link suggested by Strawberry to form a relevant yet minimal question. tag us here, once you have done that.

Comment: Dscpp, nicomp, for better or worse I wholeheartedly stand behind my comments. If I'm a bad fit for SO, then it's a pity, but SO be it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Eric said, using modern explicit JOIN syntax probably would have avoided this problem completely. You have no join criteria between the actor table and the two subqueries. So you will get every actor, with every count that is more than the average.

Also, the query could be simplified in a number of ways

```
SELECT 
  a.first_name AS fname, 
  a.last_name AS lname, 
  fpa.num_films 
FROM 
  actor as a 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
      actor_id, 
      COUNT(film_id) AS num_films 
    FROM 
      film_actor 
    GROUP BY 
      actor_id
  ) AS fpa ON a.actor_id = fpa.actor_id 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
      COUNT(*)/ COUNT(DISTINCT actor_id) AS avg_films_num 
    FROM 
      film_actor
  ) AS avg_films ON fpa.num_films > avg_films.avg_films_num 
ORDER BY 
  fname, 
  lname
```

or alternatively:

```
  SELECT 
  a.first_name AS fname, 
  a.last_name AS lname, 
  fpa.num_films 
FROM 
  actor as a 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
      actor_id, 
      COUNT(film_id) AS num_films 
    FROM 
      film_actor 
    GROUP BY 
      actor_id
  ) AS fpa ON a.actor_id = fpa.actor_id 
WHERE 
  fpa.num_films > (
    SELECT 
      COUNT(*)/ COUNT(DISTINCT actor_id) AS avg_films_num 
    FROM 
      film_actor
  ) 
ORDER BY 
  fname, 
  lname
```